# Why is my use of stringr stripping out too many characters?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, substring, stringr

In running the below demo code the user drags and drops elements from the top menu, to the section beneath, to build a dataframe. The first dataframe (output name `choices`), appearing in the upper right of the panel when running the code, renders fine. So for example if I dragged in elements Iron/Iron/Neon/Iron, in that order, `choices` renders correctly like this:

```
     choice decayCode
1 1. Iron A         1
2 2. Iron B         1
3 3. Neon A         1
4 4. Iron C         1
```

However, the second DF `choices2`, renders incorrectly as shown here (`choices2` DF is simply a mirror of the above `choices` DF but stripping out a few characters as explained below):

```
  choice decayCode
1      A         1
2      B         1
3      A         1
4      C         1
```

I would like the `choices2` DF to instead render as shown below, having stripped out the numeric prefix, ".", and space from each row of the "choice" column of the `choices` DF rendered above it while leaving in the name of each element followed by its sequential lettering suffix:

```
  choice decayCode
1 Iron A         1
2 Iron B         1
3 Neon A         1
4 Iron C         1
```

I must be doing something wrong in my use of character-stripping code using the stringr package in this line: `dat %>% mutate(choice=stringr::str_sub(choice, -1))`, where I tried stripping out the numeric/"."/space prefix of each listed element. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm open to character-stripping in base R; I prefer base R if it's possible since I'm trying to learn.

Demo code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsTreeR)
library(shiny)
library(stringr)

nodes <- list(
  list(
    text = "Pick elements from this list:",
    state = list(opened = TRUE),
    children = list(
      list(text = "Iron",type = "moveable"),
      list(text = "Neon",type = "moveable")
    )
  ),
  list(
    text = "Drag here to build DF:",
    type = "target",
    state = list(opened = TRUE)
  )
)

dnd <- list(
  always_copy = TRUE,
  inside_pos = "last", 
  is_draggable = JS(
    "function(node) {",
    "  return node[0].type === 'moveable';",
    "}"
  )
)

mytree <- jstree(
  nodes, 
  dragAndDrop = TRUE, dnd = dnd, 
  checkCallback = checkCallback,
  contextMenu = list(items = customMenu),
  types = list(moveable = list(), target = list())
)

script <- '
$(document).ready(function(){
  var LETTERS = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
  var Visited = {};
  $("#mytree").on("copy_node.jstree", function(e, data){
    var oldid = data.original.id;
    var visited = Object.keys(Visited);
    if(visited.indexOf(oldid) === -1){
      Visited[oldid] = 0;
    }else{
      Visited[oldid]++;
    }
    var letter = LETTERS[Visited[oldid]];
    var node = data.node;
    var id = node.id;
    var index = $("#"+id).index() + 1;
    var text = index + ". " + node.text + " " + letter;
    Shiny.setInputValue("choice", text);
    var instance = data.new_instance;
    instance.rename_node(node, text);
  });
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$div(class = "header", checked = NA,tags$p(tags$script(HTML(script)))),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4,jstreeOutput("mytree")),
    column(width = 8,fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("choices"),verbatimTextOutput("choices2")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output[["mytree"]] <- renderJstree(mytree)
  
  Choices <- reactiveVal(data.frame(choice = character(0), decayCode = numeric(0)))
  
  observeEvent(input[["choice"]], {Choices(rbind(Choices(), data.frame(choice = input[["choice"]], decayCode = 1)))} )

  output[["choices"]] <- renderPrint({Choices()})
  
  output[["choices2"]] <- renderPrint({
    dat <- Choices()[rep(row.names(Choices()), Choices()[,2]), 1:2]
    ifelse(nrow(dat) == 0, dat, row.names(dat) <- seq(1:nrow(dat)))
    dat <- dat %>% mutate(choice=stringr::str_sub(choice, -1))
    dat
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: The difference between this problem and your previous question (that I answered) is that previously you wanted just the last letter of `choices`.  Here you want a longer substring.  The information to allow you to work out what was going on is *all in the online doc*.  Also, Shiny is irrelevant to this your question.  Simply providing `choices1`, `choices2` and the code you used to mutate the former into the latter would have produced a much more succinct question.  Help yourself by helping others to help you by focussing only on the core issue.

Comment: OK Limey, I'm beginning to understand. I am confusing Shiny/reactivity with general dataframe manipulation issues, I conflated them. Simplifying issues is the way to go. Had I just played around with strings::str_sub(...) the way Mikko shows below in his answer, and reading the documentation, I probably would have figured this out on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another more general solution would be to use regular expressions. I think it might be a better idea to use regular expressions sou you can include cases where you want to delete numbers with more than one digit. In the regular expression I am using, `^` stands for the start of the string, `[0-9]+`, for one or more numbers, `\\.`, for a point and  , for a space. Then, `gsub` simply deletes the characters that match that pattern.

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(new = gsub("^[0-9]+\\. ", "", choice))

#     choice decayCode    new
#1 1. Iron A         1 Iron A
#2 2. Iron B         1 Iron B
#3 3. Neon A         1 Neon A
#4 4. Iron C         1 Iron C
```

Comment: I agree, the more general solution will be best. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In `str_sub()`, negative `start` and `stop` values “count backwards from the
last character” – so with `start = -1` you are extracting the substring starting from the last
character.

To remove a fixed number of characters from the start, use a positive `start` value instead:

```r
stringr::str_sub("1. Iron A", 4)
#> [1] "Iron A"
```